# Search based off a changing list of parameters

Tags: c#, search, arraylist

I have a list of these objects:

```
public class seat 
{
    public String id, tooltip;
    public String Section, Row, Number;
    public Boolean Taken;
}
```

I would like to build a function to search the elements of the class. However, I will not always be searching for all of the elements.

I know I could do this with a loop, and some if-statements. Saying something along the lines of

```
 public ArrayList searchArray(String section, String row, String number)
 {
    ArrayList searched = new ArrayList();

    foreach(seat item in seats)//seats is a list of the seat  class
    {
        if(section!="" && row!=""&&  id!="")
        {
            if(item.Section==section && item.Row==row &&item.id==id)
            searched.Add(item);
        }
        else if(section!="" && row!="")
        {
            if(item.Section==section && item.Row==row)
            searched.Add(item);
        }
        else if(row!="")
        {
            if(item.Row==row)
            searched.Add(item);
        }
        /////Continue this for all the other combinations of searching
    }
    return searched;
}
```

I could also to it several loops like

```
    if(Section!="")        
         foreach(seat item in seats)
            if(item.Section==section)
                searched.Add(item);
    seats = searched;
    search.Clear();
    if(id!="")
         foreach(seat item in seats)
            if(item.id==id)
                searched.Add(item);
    seats = searched;
    search.Clear();
    if(row!="")
        foreach(seat item in seats)
            if(item.Row==row)
                searched.Add(item);
```

So first one is tedious and requires a lot of ugly code.

The second is a little better, but requires I go through the list more than once. More specifically it requires me to go through the list for each parameter I am looking for.

Is there a way I can do this where you just add the parameters you want to look for and then search. Sort of like you generate an sql query to search.

Less important, but would be amazing if it could work, would be to even allow ranges for the search. Like `id>2 && id<12`

Comment: for starters in this part of your code `}
     return searched;` why is there an extra `}` in the foreach code block also clean up you code format in your foreach loop..

Comment: ArrayList has been obsolete for like 10 years now.  You should be using a `List` instead.

Comment: Your searching algorithm isn't even consistent between the two examples... it's unclear what you actually want. Consider a seat which has a `Section` of 5 and a `Row` of 6. Now search for a seat which has a `Section` of 5 and a `Row` of 5. Your first algorithm doesn't add it as searched, but the second would.

Comment: @Servy, Thanks for the pointer about List. I didn't know they were outdated.

Comment: @Eric Hotinger I fixed the code in the second algorithm. I forgot to clear the search result in-between filters. The code was more to show my thinking than to be 100% correct.

Comment: Also, if the person who down-voted  my post it reading this, is it possible to get an explanation. According to stack overflow "Use your down-votes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." I would like to know how I should change my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where `IEnumerable<>` is your friend!

```
IEnumerable<seat> query = seats.AsEnumerable();

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(section))
    query = query.Where(s => s.Section == section);

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
    query = query.Where(s => s.Row == row);

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    query = query.Where(s => s.Id == id);

List<seat> results = query.ToList(); // deferred execution
```

Comment: You also only need to call `AsEnumerable` if you're using `var`.  If you explicitly type the variable it's superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList searched = new ArrayList(
             seats.Where(c => c.Section == section && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(section))
                  .Where(c => c.Row == row && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                  .Where(c => c.id == id && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)).ToList());
```

Comment: You can't use LINQ on `ArrayList` as it doesn't impelement generic `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: from the above code
//seats is a list of the seat  class

Comment: The OP meant rather `ArrayList` as this is the return type